# how to print multiple copies in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printdialog, pdfium

I am currently using the below code for printing a pdf file from database. I am using pdfium for viewing the pdf file and for printing I use PrintDialog box. I can print the pdf file in a single copy only but in a multiple copies I didn't get it

Here is my Code:

```
        PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        int pageForPrint = 0;

        pd.PrintPage += (s, z) =>
        {
            using (PdfBitmap bmp = new PdfBitmap((int)z.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, (int)z.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height, true))
            {

                //Render to PdfBitmap using page's Render method with FPDF_PRINTING flag
                pdfViewer1.Document.Pages[pageForPrint].Render
                    (bmp,
                    0,
                    0,
                    (int)z.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width,
                    (int)z.PageBounds.Height,
                    Patagames.Pdf.Enums.PageRotate.Normal, Patagames.Pdf.Enums.RenderFlags.FPDF_PRINTING);

                //Draw rendered image to printer's graphics surface
                z.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp.Image,
                    (int)z.PageSettings.PrintableArea.X,
                    (int)z.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Y);

                //Print next page
                if (pageForPrint < pdfViewer1.Document.Pages.Count)
                {
                    pageForPrint++;
                    z.HasMorePages = true;
                }
               ;
            }
        };

        //start printing routine
        pd.Print();
```

}

Comment: You havent set the printer to print the number of copies..

Comment: thank you for your reply. pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2; I try this... but it is only two copies. Should I use loop? To print multiple copies?

Comment: the printer should print number of copies of whatever you send to print.. you shouldnt need a loop

Comment: Sorry @BugFinder I didnt get it . Got error.

Comment: what error? you said below you got 2 copies.. implying it worked, the printer should denote the number of copies the code works out what overall to print..

Comment: It prints only in two if i set it to pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;   but if the user want 3 or 5 copies it didnt work it prints two again.

Comment: Then you set copies to the number they wanted... Im not seeing your struggle.. so if user types 10, set copies to 10.. if they want 1 make it 1

Answer (score 0):

Use PrinterSettings and pass

```
pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = [numberofpages]
```

Comment: pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;  I try this... but it is only two copies. How I set the numberofpages. Should I use loop?

Comment: Yes, a loop should suffice. And after your loop, print.

Comment: here my code in loop. where should I will put this in my code.  for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCopies; i++)
            {
             //i didnt know what will happen here
              
            }

Answer (score 0):

you can use PrintToPrinter  option as follows

```
public virtual void PrintToPrinter (
    int nCopies,
    bool collated,
    int startPageN,
    int endPageN
)

Parameters
nCopies
Indicates the number of copies to print.
collated
Indicates whether to collate the pages.
startPageN
Indicates the first page to print.
endPageN
Indicates the last page to print.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms226031(v=vs.90)
```